# How to get a button in template to change a model? Django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to build an app with a like-dislike functionality such that by clicking a like button you get added to a string of users that liked and get removed from the dislike string if you were there. How can i do that? I added some of the relevent code:

the button:

`<button type='submit'> Like </button>`

And the model im trying to change:

```
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    auther = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    views_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    user_like_id = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length = 10000000, default = "")
    user_dislike_id = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length = 10000000, default = "")
```

Comment: You will need to make use of a Boolean Field. Every time the user clicks like, check if he has already liked the post. You will also need to use a many to many connection to get relation with the post. There are thousands of videos regarding this topic, please check YouTube and other stack overflow questions

Comment: My problem is how to get the button to react, i already set the structure even if it is not ideal.

Comment: So you want the button to display a heart when not liked